# Cucumber 4 jvm rerun failed tests in jenkins using shell command

Tags: jenkins, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I added execution command to my jenkins shell command:

```
cd apitests && ./gradlew cucumber -Pthreads=${THREADS} -Ptags="not @notReady" && [ -s rerun/failed_scenarios.txt ] && ./gradlew cucumber -PfeaturePath='@rerun/failed_scenarios.txt' -Pthreads=80 || echo "File empty"
```

In gradle I added task with cucumber options I set to save failed test to file:

```
cucumber {
    threads = 50
    glue = 'classpath:com.sixtleasing.cucumber.steps'
    plugin = ["pretty", "html:target/zucchini", "json:target/zucchini.json", "rerun:rerun/failed_scenarios.txt"] 
    (...)
}
```

Everything works when all tests are green. The problem starts when one of tests fails. In that case I see in the console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: The execution failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

why? If I run commands separatly it works but in jenkins as a one shell command it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If the first invocation of gradle with cucumber fails, then nothing to the right of `&&` is executed.  This is because the return code of the the gradlew process is non-zero if the build fails.

Give this a try:

```
cd apitests && ./gradlew cucumber -Pthreads=${THREADS} -Ptags="not @notReady" || ( [ -s rerun/failed_scenarios.txt ] && ./gradlew cucumber -PfeaturePath='@rerun/failed_scenarios.txt' -Pthreads=80 || echo "File empty" )
```